# Is it advisable to have a countdown for a limited free account in a register form?

Tags: website-design, forms

This is a register form, it offers free account for the first 50 users, I wonder if it's good or common to put an account countdown for it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Franco.  Can you clarify your question a bit? "Good" for whom? Optimizing for what? What are you hoping to accomplish by including or excluding a countdown?

Comment: Sure, thanks. If it's good in terms of getting on people a feeling of urgency and trustability that the 50 free account actually is running. I also wonder if with the countdown people would sign faster than without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me and based on the mistakes i have made in the past, putting any kind of condition for the user is not a good idea. Instead of showing countdown, you could tell them more about advantages of opening an account with your service. They should find value in opening an account at first place.

People would die to open an account only if you are offering them free money or huge discounts. Otherwise it does not make sense.

Comment: Right, but yeah, I was always considering to tell about the advantages of opening an account. Also, the "big" offering is having the account for Free, but only to the first 50. Do you mean at the end that a countdown just doesn't offer any benefit at all?

Comment: Take a user survey, see what do they think since you are deigning your application for them.